# Ошибка С4996 в C++\CLI в marshal.h

Tags: visual-c++

Возникла ошибка при компилировании кода с помощью marshal.
**Код:**

```
#include <msclr\marshal_windows.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <string>
//...
short year,day;
String^ y;
String^ d;
char* temp;
marshal_context^ marshal = gcnew marshal_context();
temp = marshal->marshal_as<char*>(d);
if (day==0) d="";
if (day!=0) temp=_itoa(day,temp,10);
d = marshal->marshal_as<System::String^>(temp);
temp = marshal->marshal_as<char*>(y);
temp=_itoa(year,temp,10);
y=marshal->marshal_as<System::String^>(temp);
```

**Ошибки:**
error C4996:'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included. Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.
(Ссылается на marshal.h, на строку с макросом, обозначающим эту ошибку)

Как исправить?
Visual Studio 2010
P.S: #pragma warning(disable:4996) и т.п. почему-то не работают.

Comment: Ваш template<> не поддерживает указаный тип. Хоть строку с ошибкой укажите что б не гадать.  p. s.  #pragma warning ошибки не выключает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в строках:

```
temp = marshal->marshal_as<char*>(d);
```

и

```
temp = marshal->marshal_as<char*>(y);
```

Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384856(v=vs.100).aspx) ошибка C4996 возникает при попытке преобразования типов которые не поддерживаются.
А [таблица преобразования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384865(v=vs.100).aspx) о невозможности преобразования к типу `char*`.